# Single page website- fit content to 100% of screen

Tags: jquery, css

trying to achieve that:

Single page website- fit content to 100% of screen

I have an-

```
html{
 body{
  #header
  #page1
  #page2
  #page3
 }
}
```

i am trying to fit every page(id) to width: 100%, and height of 100%
so, if the user will zoom out from the page and he is now on #page1 div, he won't see any other div
because #page1 div is set to take 100%, width and height, no matter what is the window size.

I tried to accomplish this by setting the:

```
html,body{width:100%; height:100%}
```

my #page1 has a background-image and with the above css, it worked, if i zoom out it set the page to 100% height and width.

and even

```
#header, #page1, #page2{min-width:100%; min-height:100%}
```

how can I accomplish that effect?

- i only want to give the user **the illusion that it's really a page** and not just a div

---

i'll try to explain my self even better, suppose i am a user navigate to my site and scroll down to page2, i get there and zoom out from the page.. even if I zoom to show only 20% from the page will see only 20% from page2(div) I will not see the other div's(page1, page3), same as for re-size the browser window
if I re-size it it will keep the same proportions as it was opened 100%.

**Each div(page) will scale to 100% height of the window.**

**What i am trying to achieve is that: zoomed out to 20%, look at the scroll bar, you don't see other div's**
[image: What i am trying to achieve is that: zoomed out to 20%, look at the scroll bar ..]

Comment: "with the above css, it worked" so whats the problem? please make a jsfiddle.net with an example and explain what exactly doesnt work.

Comment: it only worked to the #page1, having an background image

Comment: you need to do that using js, calculate height and width of the window on load and also on resize. And apply the same height and width to the  #page1, #page2 etc

Comment: #Tushar, sound like that what i am looking for, can you post an example showing that?

Comment: Do you want it like this: http://jsbin.com/bikayuco/4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got you right, it is possible with plain CSS - isn't it?

## Version with native scrollbar

---

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
.section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#page1 {
  background: blue;
}
#page2 {
  background: yellow;
}
#page3 {
  background: green;
}
```

**JS** (for keeping the percentage scroll offset when zooming)

```
var scrollOffset = [0,0,0]
var $win = $(window);
var $doc = $(document);

$win
.on('scroll', function(){
    // this is needed because scroll is triggered when zooming before the zoom event
    scrollOffset[2] = scrollOffset[1];
    scrollOffset[1] = scrollOffset[0];
    scrollOffset[0] = 100 / $win.height() * $win.scrollTop();
    console.log('scroll event', scrollOffset);
})
.on('resize', function(){
    // set back the history because of multiple zooming events
    scrollOffset[0] = scrollOffset[1];
    scrollOffset[1] = scrollOffset[2];
    scrollOffset[2] = 0;
    console.log('zoom event', scrollOffset);
    window.scrollTo(0, scrollOffset[0] / 100 * $win.height());
})
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqteo

## Version without native scrollbar but JS "scrolling"

---

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  overflow:hidden; // remove for "normal" content scrolling
}
.section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#page1 {
  background: blue;
}
#page2 {
  background: yellow;
}
#page3 {
  background: green;
}
```

**JS** (simple example for page "snapping")

```
$(function(){
  var top = 0;
  $('.section').on('click', function(){
    top -= 100;
    $('.section').animate({'top': top +'%'});
  });
})
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ldmBJ

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated demo including navigation. [DEMO](http://codepen.io/tusharbandal/pen/foDtc)

jQuery for div's height and width.

you can check the height and width changes on window resize.

You can minus the header height from `windowHeight` if needed.

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height() - $('#header').height()
```

Comment: can you please update your demo so it will contain more div's? what css parameters should i give to body and html?

Comment: also, if i make it responsive(menu if positioned fixed), it will work ok, even if i set the overflow to hidden?

Comment: can you please invite me to chat? its not working as expected

Comment: this is my mail id tusharbandal777@gmail.com